# Holding an image for runtime updating in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have an image I'd like to display using `imshow()` and to **update** at runtime: say I'd like to run a corner detection algorithm then **display the corner on this same image** - like in MATLAB `figure  plot(), hold plot()` - the **`hold`** keyword hold the previous image/graph and enables a new plot on the same figure.

Is this possible to do with OpenCV? If yes, how can I do it?

thanks

Comment: just call `imshow` (same window, same image) again after manipulating the image data. Don't forget some `cv::waitKey()` after imshow otherwise there might not be enough ui time to display the image or not enough time for the user to SEE the changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, you don't need to hold it in order to update drawing. You just need to draw what you want to the image and then `imshow` the image. There you go.

---

Look at the following example from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/core/random_generator_and_text/random_generator_and_text.html):

```
int Displaying_Big_End( Mat image, char* window_name, RNG rng )
{
  Size textsize = getTextSize("OpenCV forever!", CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 3, 5, 0);
  Point org((window_width - textsize.width)/2, (window_height - textsize.height)/2);
  int lineType = 8;

  Mat image2;

  for( int i = 0; i < 255; i += 2 )
  {
    image2 = image - Scalar::all(i);
    putText( image2, "OpenCV forever!", org, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 3,
           Scalar(i, i, 255), 5, lineType );

    imshow( window_name, image2 );
    if( waitKey(DELAY) >= 0 )
      { return -1; }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

[image]

Pay attention to the `imshow( window_name, image2 )`, we don't do anything to hold the image, just use the loop to draw incrementally (by `putText()`) on the image. The image will update dynamically accordingly.

Comment: @herohuyongtao thanks for the answer! As far as I understand you, you'll see the **final image** by the end with all the textbox added. You'll not see the **intermediate results**. Meaning: the result **before** you add a textbox and **after** you add a textbox - this is what I need: see the image before adding a feature to it and after adding a feature to it.

Comment: @PhonoDots No. You see how the image changes over-time.

Comment: @herohuyongtao great... this is exactely what I need - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no concept of `hold` in OpenCV.
Basically, `cv::imshow()` will just update the window with whatever *image* it gets.

To "overlay" you actually need to create a new image (or reuse an existing one), draw on this new image and/or update it, e.g. with your detected corners, and call `imshow()` again with this updated image.